# how i can put full screen mode in android (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

Using this code

```
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

but the notch is hidden

Comment: can u upload screenshot of the view after adding full screen option?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to put full screen mode:

```
private fun hideSystemUI() {
    // Enables regular immersive mode.
    // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
    // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
            // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            // Hide the nav bar and status bar
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
}
```

and to back to your normal screen you can use:

```
// Shows the system bars by removing all the flags
// except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
private fun showSystemUI() {
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
}
```

FOR MORE INFO CHECK THIS LINK:https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive